# OWASP CRS Anomaly scoring, ModSecurity WAF

Tags: waf, mod-security, anomaly-detection

I'm getting into OWASP CRS with ModSecurity and was investigating the way OWASP calculate the anomaly score in the REQUEST-901-INITIALIZATION.conf they set the following lines:

```
setvar:'tx.anomaly_score=0',\
setvar:'tx.anomaly_score_pl1=0',\
setvar:'tx.anomaly_score_pl2=0',\
setvar:'tx.anomaly_score_pl3=0',\
setvar:'tx.anomaly_score_pl4=0',\
```

and in the REQUEST-949-BLOCKING-EVALUATION.conf they do the following:

```
SecRule TX:PARANOIA_LEVEL "@ge 1" \
    "id:949060,\
    phase:2,\
    pass,\
    t:none,\
    nolog,\
    setvar:'tx.anomaly_score=+%{tx.anomaly_score_pl1}'"
enter preformatted text here
SecRule TX:PARANOIA_LEVEL "@ge 2" \
"id:949061,\
phase:2,\
pass,\
t:none,\
nolog,\
setvar:'tx.anomaly_score=+%{tx.anomaly_score_pl2}'"
```

Q1: Of course the paranoia level will be 1, 2, 3 or 4, so why do the "@ge 1"? which will be evaluated on every paranoia level?

Q2: When they do the setVar `"setvar:'tx.anomaly_score=+%{tx.anomaly_score_pl2}"` the equation will be `tx.anomaly_score=tx.anomaly_score+tx.anomaly_score_pl2`; is that right ? And how is this logically applicable if my request is being validated by multiple rules?

Q3: I would like to have a detailed example of how the OWASP CRS calculate the anomaly score and use it to deny the requests.

Answer (score 0):

Q1: `TX:PARANOIA_LEVEL "@ge 1"` means about `if TX:PARANOIA_LEVEL >= 1`, and all four PL will match. Please read the reason above the [rule](https://github.com/coreruleset/coreruleset/blob/v3.4/dev/rules/REQUEST-949-BLOCKING-EVALUATION.conf#L16-L17).

Q2: yes, the `+=` is same as you wrote there.

> And how this logically applicable if my request is being validated by
> multiple rules?

The rules were evaluated one-by-one, as you (or the rule maker) listed them (grouped by phases). If a rule contains a value-giving action like above, then just evaluated - but the TX (or tx) means transaction, so for every request has its own TX collection.

Q3: I think the best starting point would be [this Modsecurity documentation](https://www.modsecurity.org/CRS/Documentation/anomaly.html). It's a bit outdated, but the basics are there. A quick summary: every rule has a severity level, which could be one of notice (with points 2), warning (3), error (4), critical (5) (these are defined in [this file](https://github.com/coreruleset/coreruleset/blob/v3.4/dev/rules/REQUEST-901-INITIALIZATION.conf#L118). Every rule is activated on different PLs (paranoia levels), so the chosen score (variable) will be incremented by the severity value.